# MVVM light Messenger Action execute after first time Windows Uinversal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

I have 2 classes and want to send object using Messenger while navigating from page to another and it works but only when navigate to the page and come back then try again not from first try.
ManivViewModel code:

```
public void GoToDetial(object parameter)
{
    try
    {
        var arg = parameter as ItemClickEventArgs;
        var item = arg.ClickedItem as Item;
        Messenger.Default.Send<Item>(item, "Mess");
        _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(DescriptionPage));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

DescriptionViewModel code:

```
public DescriptionViewModel(IRSSDataService rssService, INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService)
{
    _dataService = rssService;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _dialogService = dialogService;

    load();

    LoadCommand = new RelayCommand(load);
    GoToUrlCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(GoToUrl);
    ShareSocialCommand = new RelayCommand(ShareSocial);
}

private void load()
{            
    Messenger.Default.Register<Item>(
         this,
         "Mess",
         selectedItem =>
         {
             Item = selectedItem;
             // Prepare content to share
             RegisterForShare();
             GetFromHTML(Item.Link);
         });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it. I just need to pass in "true" to the Register call in the SimpleIoc to create the instance of the DescriptionViewModel immediately like this

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DescriptionViewModel>(true);
```